# Do $C_c(I)$ and $C(I)$ coincide for an open interval $I$ and are the functions in $C_c(I)$ even uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, uniform-continuity

Most probably this question boils down to my confusion about the correct definition of $C_c(\Omega)$, but:

If $\Omega$ is a topological space and $\operatorname{supp}f:=\overline{\{x\in\Omega:f(x)\ne0\}}$ for any $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$, then $C_c(\Omega)$ is the set of those $f$ for which $\operatorname{supp}f$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$.

Now, if $\Omega$ happens to be a subspace of another topological space, there is some room for confusion.

### **Question 1**:

Consider the simple example of an open interval $I=(0,T)$, $T>0$. I wondered whether the spaces $C_c(I)$, $C_0(I)$ (vanishing at infinity) and $C(I)$ (continuous) actually coincide. It's clear to me that this is true, for $I$ replaced by $\overline I$, but I'm unsure whether it holds for $I$ itself as well.

I think the answer is *no*, but I would like to know whether if $f\in C_c(I)$, can we infer that $\operatorname{supp}f$ is the intersection of $I$ with a compact subset of $\mathbb R$?

### **Question 2**:

Moreover, I would like to know whether a function in $C_c(I)$ is even *uniformly* continuous.

If I'm not mistaken, we should have the following result: If $\Omega$ is a locally compact metric space $\Omega$, then any function in $C_0(\Omega)$ is uniformly continuous. Since $C_c(\Omega)\subseteq C_0(\Omega)$, the same holds true for any function in $C_c(\Omega)$.

Now, if I'm not terribly wrong, any subset of a locally compact metric space is again a locally compact metric space (endowed with the restriction of the inherited metric) and since $\mathbb R$ is obviously locally compact this should be applicable for $\Omega=I$.

Comment: What is an "environmental space"?

Comment: @PeterMorfe What I've meant was that it is a subspace of another topological space.

Comment: "Any subset of a locally compact metric space is again a locally compact metric space" is not true. E.g. $\mathbb Q$ is a non-locally compact subspace of  $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Hm, I see. However, $I$ is surely a locally compact metric space and so we should still be able to apply the mentioned result for $\Omega=I$. Or do you doubt that this is correct as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:**  Given $T > 0$, what are the compact subsets of $(0,T)$?  (Here the topology of $(0,T)$ is the relative topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ or, in other words, restrict the usual absolute value metric to $(0,T)$.)  This seems to be one of the sources of confusion.  In particular, the answer is *not* "the intersection of a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $(0,T)$."

**Hint 2:**  Given a locally compact metric space $\Omega$, what is the definition of $C_{0}(\Omega)$?  Is it possible to be more specific when $\Omega = (0,T)$?  $(0,T)$ is a very simple locally compact metric space due to the ordering it inherits from the real line, hence the definition of $C_{0}(\Omega)$ can be made much less abstract than in general.

As for the rest, yes, if $\Omega$ is a locally compact metric space, then every function in $C_{0}(\Omega)$ is uniformly continuous.

It is not true that *any* subset of a locally compact topological space (or even metric space) is locally compact.  For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally compact.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space#Properties) for a characterization of subsets that are locally compact.

Answer (score 0):

$C_c(I)$ is the set of all functions whose supports are compact subsets of $I.$ In particular, even though the support of a function like $f(x) = \chi_{(0,1)}(x)$, defined on $I = (0, 1)$ might seem to be $[0, 1],$ in the space $I$ the support is the set $(0,1),$ since $I$ can't see the two endpoints.

All functions in $C_c(I)$ are uniformly continuous. There are many ways of seeing this; the quickest is that any function with compact domain is uniformly continuous, and a compactly supported function behaves very much like a function with compact domain. You're also right that your other argument implies this, although applying it is overkill because the proof goes "for any $\epsilon,$ my fiunction is smaller than $\epsilon/2$ outside of some compact set and uniformly continuous on that compact set, so it's $\epsilon$-uniformly contninuous if I have some local compactness to make sure the boundary isn't too bad." In the end it is much trickier than showing $C_c(I)$ has this property.

Comment: Thank you for your post. While everything you wrote is clear to me, I'm not sure what your answer to my first question actually is. (a) Do $C_c(I)$, $C_0(I)$ and $C(I)$ coincide? (b) Can we write $\operatorname{supp}f$ as an intersection of $I$ and a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ (or does this actually boil down to the fact that if $I$ is any subset of a topological space $\Omega$, then a subset $K$ of $I$ is compact in $I$ if and only if it is compact in $\Omega$)?

Comment: (a) No, they do not. The constant function $f(x) = 1$ belongs to $C(I)$ but to neither $C_c(I)$ nor $C_0(I).$ To see that $C_c(I)$ is strictly smaller than $C(I),$ take a piecewise linear function defined by $f(a) = 0, f((a+b)/2) = 17, f(b) = 0$ and then restrict the domain to $(a,b).$

(b) The support of $f$ is a closed subset of $I,$ which is the intersection of $I$ and a closed subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}.$ $K = C \cap [a, b]$ is then a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so that the support of $f$ is the intersection of $(a,b)$ and $K.$